# How to construct Target Url using Assign Message policy in APIGEE?

Tags: apigee

i want to construct or modify target URL on run time when the proxy flow reaches to target endpoint based on the provided condition, i don't want to hard code it want to fetch it from kvm but when i am trying to fetch it from kvm it was not working.

Comment: Do the following steps:
1. Declare KVM in KVM policy
2. In Assign Message policy use Assign Variable and set target.url equals to defining KVM variable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a KVM and make it encrypted.
2. use KVM policy to get the encrypted value form KVM.

   `<KeyValueMapOperations async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Key-Value-Map-Operations-dark-sky" mapIdentifier="encrpt">
   <DisplayName>Key Value Map Operations</DisplayName>
   <Properties/>
   <ExclusiveCache>false</ExclusiveCache>
   <ExpiryTimeInSecs>300</ExpiryTimeInSecs>
   <Get assignTo="private.targetURL" index="1">
       <Key>
           <Parameter>KVM-key</Parameter>
       </Key>
   </Get>
   <Scope>environment</Scope>
   </KeyValueMapOperations>`

*Private should be used only if using encrypted value. foo is the key and mapIdentifier should be the KVM you created.

You can directly use private.targetURL in path of your target endpoint.

```
<HTTPTargetConnection>
    <LoadBalancer>
        <Server name="targetapi"/>
    </LoadBalancer>
    <Path>/forecast/{private.targetURL}/</Path>
</HTTPTargetConnection>
```

Comment: I did the same way you are doing except I did not use a encrypted KVM, is it mandatory here?